# How to wait for events when using StampedLock?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, stampedlock

Java's `StampedLock` does not support `Condition` variables. As such, how can one implement the following pseudo code with StampedLocks?

```
public class Example
{
    private final List<Integer> queue = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock writeLock = lock.writeLock();
    private final Condition dataAdded = writeLock.newCondition();

    public void waitForData()
    {
      writeLock.lock();
      try
      {
        while (queue.isEmpty())
          dataAdded.await();
      }
      finally
      {
        writeLock.unlock();
      }
    }
}
```

Specifically, how do I wait on the event without condition variables? The only approaches that come to mind are:

Old-school `Object.wait()`:

```
Object dataAdded = new Object();

public void waitForData()
{
  synchronized (dataAdded)
  {
    while (queue.isEmpty())
      dataAdded.wait();
  }
}
```

`ReentrantLock` with a corresponding `Condition`:

```
Lock writeLock = new ReentrantLock();
Condition dataAdded = new Condition();

public void waitForData()
{
  writeLock.lock();
  try
  {
    while (queue.isEmpty())
      dataAdded.await();
  }
  finally
  {
    writeLock.unlock();
  }
}
```

It seems kind of odd to use multiple locking mechanisms to achieve this. Further, when I come back from `wait()` or `await()` I am not guaranteed to be able to acquire a `StampedLock` write lock.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I am having the same issue, but I am unable to find a solution. Many Thanks.

Comment: @3xypn0s I did not; otherwise, I would have added an answer here. I ended up moving back to `ReentrantReadWriteLock` and it was good enough for my use-case.